# Adding XML declaration and DOCTYPE to XML with VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I can't figure out how to add simple XML and Doctype declarations to an XML file I am generating. I'm creating and adding nodes fine but that code doesn't seem to work for doing this. My code is as follows:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

Set objDoctype = xmlDoc.createElement("DOCTYPE")
xmlDoc.appendChild objTop
```

I found this link: http://www.example-code.com/vbscript/xml_doctype.asp which doesn't seem to work for me because it looks like they are editing the file as a TXT file.

Also, I need to add this declaration to the top of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Thanks for your help!

### EDIT

What I would like to see on the top of the XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "shopstyle-catalog.dtd">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a complete, but short example of the desired output (to clarify moot points: DOCTYPE? HTML? HTML5? XHTML? XML?)

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner, I just updated that. Let me know if that helps clarify it. Thanks!

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is, in fact, the default. It's not required unless your XML document has a different version or encoding.

Comment: @Tomalak, when I open the file after creating it and saving it to the server, it doesn't have the XML declaration on top.

Comment: So? The XML declaration is optional (unless the document does not conform to the default).

Comment: @Tomalak, what exactly do you mean it's optional? It's not optional for the XML that I'm creating. I need it in there in order for it to work with an API I creating it for according to their documentation.

Comment: It is perfectly optional. Maybe the tools you use are broken? The XML spec does not require an XML declaration, since all of the fields have default values. I'm running out of ways to put this... ;)

Comment: Ok, I'm just saying that in the documentation for this API, it says `Product feeds must be properly encoded and contain proper namespace declarations in order to validate. Specifically, this requires:

1. The XML encoding declaration on the first line of the file
2. A DOCTYPE declaration which will import entity definitions
3. Version-sepcific namespace declarations in the <catalog/> attributes.`

I've completed #3 but this question is specifically about 1 and 2. I'm just going by what they're stating on their end?

Comment: Well, it's a common misconception that an XML declaration is necessary. Every XML parser on earth can deal with XML documents that have none, even their API will. The only implication of a missing XML declaration is that your document must be XML v1.0 and UTF-8 (which is a target that's hard to miss). It won't *hurt* to add a declaration that states the defaults, but it is redundant.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've sent over the XML for review but let's say I wanted to Figure out how to add that declaration to state the defaults just in case?

Comment: Have you had a look at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I found no easy way to add a doctype declaration to an existing document<sup>(*)</sup> via the XMLDOM/MSXML2 API. It [appears to be impossible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757901(v=vs.85).aspx) (see the "Remarks" section). Quote, emphasis mine:

> You cannot create a node of type NODE_DOCUMENT, **NODE_DOCUMENT_TYPE**, NODE_ENTITY, or NODE_NOTATION.

However, this is a trivial task with XSLT. This tiny transformation adds an XML declaration and a doctype to your input document - plus it transcodes the input to any output encoding you specify (I strongly recommend leaving it at UTF-8, though).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" />
  <xsl:output doctype-system="shopstyle-catalog.dtd" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The rest of the input document is copied verbatim.

There are countless examples of how to apply XSL stylesheets to XML documents in various languages and environments, so I'm not going to go into this here.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> If you create a document *from scratch*, there is a way: Instead of trying to create the doctype declaration programmatically, you can use [the `loadXML()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754585(v=vs.85).aspx) to load a skeleton XML string that already contains the wanted doctype declaration.